# Self-Questioning in TV interviews

Tags: syntactic-analysis

More and more in TV interviews -- and only on TV, by the way, never in "real" life -- I hear people using what I call, for lack of any other name, "Self-Questioning.". Example: "Do I regret saying what I did that morning?  Yes, I do.  Do I wish I had said something else instead?  Of course.  But we cannot go backwards, so what's done is done.". Sometimes there are three self-questions in the series, but usually there are only two.  I don't know the official name for this, if there even is one.  All I know is that I loathe it.  Has anyone else noticed this confessional-like speech pattern?  I am positive I never encountered it until recently, and unfortunately seems to be gaining in popularity.

Comment: Hello, Grace. Have you a question one would judge appropriate here? "Has anyone else noticed this confessional-like speech pattern?" is asking for opinions on style changes, not for analysis of the fundamental workings of English (grammar, semantics ...) that ELU aims to provide. // Soliloquy was common even in Shakespeare's day.

Comment: Might I suggest a new title along the lines of "what is the name for the rhetoric of self-questioning/answering in TV interviews?"

Comment: That's funny.  I have thought of this technique as a way to catch the viewer's attention before answering the question - like we're all ADHD and need a little prodding before launching into the real story..."I'll pique your curiosity with this leading question I'm asking myself...then when I have your attention, I'll answer it in a witty and pithy manner!" It is a little annoying, isn't it?

Comment: As well as voting to close, on account of it being a duplicate, I have also voted for it, because I believe it to be a good question.

Comment: There are questions (hypothetical example: “Has person X committed a crime?”) that look like yes/no questions, where one could conceivably answer “yes” or “no”. In the real world, situations are rarely so black and white; the truth often falls into a gray area between “yes” and “no”. Reframing the question is a technique to parse the question into bite-sized pieces that may be more easily answered “yes” or “no”; e.g., “Did Joe the pawnbroker burglarize Jane’s house? No. Did he come into possession of property stolen from her house? Yes. Did he *knowingly* traffic in stolen goods? …” … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I don’t understand the annoyance. P.S. “Have you stopped beating your wife?” is a classic example of a question that sounds like a yes/no question that isn’t really. P.P.S. I believe that I *do* hear this rhetorical question-parsing “in real life”, and I don’t see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

While it would help if you rephrased this as an actual question ...

These are in fact perfect examples of the [Rhetorical Question](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question).